# How to get a deployed site after I deploy moralis-admin-cli?

Tags: javascript

I have started to follow the YouTube video "[Ultimate NFT Programming Tutorial - FULL COURSE](https://youtu.be/tBMk1iZa85Y)" by Filip Martinsson to be able to set up everything to be able mint and sell NFT's.

I have followed his code precisely...checked everything three times...and I am at the area where I need to [deploy](https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-server/tools/moralis-admin-cli#deploy) `moralis-admin-cli`. I have placed a copy of what is going on shown below:

```
C:\metadata-static-app>moralis-admin-cli deploy
Specify Moralis Api Key: SOkdwGDLfrv4oGa
Specify Moralis Api Secret: 7FbMvOOk1EGrKKI
Following servers were found:
(0) ABC
(1) abcd
What server do you want to connect to?: 1

C:\metadata-static-app>
```

When I say to connect to a server, it just comes back blank as is shown in my example. It should say and show the following:

```
What server do you want to connect to?: 1
Deployed successfully!
Site is available at: https//lqm5lovruqm4.moralisweb3.com"
```

I am not sure if something else needs to be added to my laptop or really what am I doing wrong. I am really stuck. I hope someone can help me and give me some direction in what is wrong.

Comment: I really hope you changed your keys since posting them here

Comment: The keys I showed in my example were changed before posting this query. Those are not the real key numbers...I changed them so I could post what was happening.